# pretty formatting of string variable with multiple "\n"

Tags: string, go

I am having some issues formatting string variables with multiple `\n` (carriage returns) in it.  I have a string variable that has stored in it the following:

> "1. Check the connections \n2. Have the firewall settings been checked \n3. Check switch/network connections \n4. Contact admin"

Now, I want to print the line so that it looks like this:

```
Remedy:                  1.  Check the connections
                         2.  Have the firewall setting been checked
                         3.  Check switch/network connections
                         4.  Contact admin
```

However, in my program when I run the output line:

```
fmt.Println("remedy:\t\t\t\t" + alt.Remedy)
```

It comes up like this:

```
remedy:                         1. Check the connections
2. Have the firewall settings been checked
3. Check switch/network connections
4. Contact admin
```

How do I get it so that by issuing that command, all 4 options are listed in the same column?  In this example, I want options 2, 3, and 4 listed under the #1 option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing in Go to do this for you.

Instead, you can split the string into lines and format them accordingly.

Here is an example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    str := "1. Check the connections \n2. Have the firewall settings been checked \n3. Check switch/network connections \n4. Contact admin"
    // Split the string into lines.
    parts := strings.Split(str, "\n")
    // Iterate over the lines.
    for i, s := range parts {
        if i == 0 {
            // First line: start with "Remedy"
            fmt.Printf("Remedy:\t\t\t%s\n", s)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("       \t\t\t%s\n", s)
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
Remedy:         1. Check the connections 
                2. Have the firewall settings been checked 
                3. Check switch/network connections 
                4. Contact admin
```

**Note**: there are probably a few other ways to do this, I just picked this one.

Comment: Take a look as peterSO suggests at [raw string literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals).

Comment: Sure, but if you're building your own string, why would you need a formatting function? I was assuming this was coming from elsewhere. But then again, OP is a little unclear about the origin of the string.

Comment: Glad to hear it, but please clarify your scenario in the question. If this is for hard-coded strings, then @peterSO's solution is definitely preferable.

Answer (score 2):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [String literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals)
>
> A string literal represents a string constant obtained from
>   concatenating a sequence of characters. There are two forms: raw
>   string literals and interpreted string literals.
>
> Raw string literals are character sequences between back quotes, as in
>   `foo`. Within the quotes, any character may appear except back quote.
>   The value of a raw string literal is the string composed of the
>   uninterpreted (implicitly UTF-8-encoded) characters between the
>   quotes; in particular, backslashes have no special meaning and the
>   string may contain newlines. Carriage return characters ('\r') inside
>   raw string literals are discarded from the raw string value.

---

Use a [raw string literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals). For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    message := `
Remedy:                  1.  Check the connections
                         2.  Have the firewall setting been checked
                         3.  Check switch/network connections
                         4.  Contact admin
`

    fmt.Print(message[1:])
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/pdgAoYnBIch

Output:

```
Remedy:                  1.  Check the connections
                         2.  Have the firewall setting been checked
                         3.  Check switch/network connections
                         4.  Contact admin
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Marc's answer, but I would do it this way. It's simpler, shorter and cleaner:

Replace each newline character in the source `string` with a newline plus the indentation that non-first lines need. You may use [`strings.Replace()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replace) for this.

The source string to be formatted:

`s := "1. Check the connections \n2. Have the firewall settings been checked \n3. Check switch/network connections \n4. Contact admin"`

And the formatting is a simple line:

```
fmt.Println("Remedy:     ", strings.Replace(s, "\n", "\n             ", -1))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/7UnpO2Va1GE)):

```
Remedy:      1. Check the connections 
             2. Have the firewall settings been checked 
             3. Check switch/network connections 
             4. Contact admin
```

Answer (score -2):

Since you are storing the "remedies" together in a string, there isn't much you can do other than include spacing in your string var.

```
"1. Check the connections\n\t\t\t\t2. Have the firewall settings been checked\n\t\t\t\t3. Check switch/network connections\n\t\t\t\t4. Contact admin"
```

I would suggest saving them as a slice and iterating to print:

```
package main

import "fmt"

var remedy = []string{
    "Check the connections",
    "Have the firewall settings been checked",
    "Check switch/network connections",
    "Contact admin",
}

func main() {
    fmt.Print("remedy:")
    for i := range remedy {
        if i == 0 {
            fmt.Printf("%13d. %s\n", i+1, remedy[i])
            continue
        }
        fmt.Printf("%20d. %s\n", i+1, remedy[i])
    }
}
```

[Example on play](https://play.golang.org/p/iIBxlimbgdw)

Comment: If keeping them all in a single string variable is a requirement, Marc's answer is best IMO.

Comment: Take a look as peterSO suggests at [raw string literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals).

Comment: Yes, but the reason I didn't love that answer is because it's modifying the variable op's trying to use. Marc's answer is the only one that works with his `string`.

Comment: Any solution will require modifying something, because the current behavior is not the desired behavior.

Comment: Obviously, but some changes will require less refactor than others. Since all op's given is that he has a string variable with `\n`, it should be assumed that's the input and it needs to be modified to provide the desired output. Rather than answering "change your input", answers should be "modify with xyz".